# Open file in editor programmatically after renaming

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am exporting a file and while exporting ,I am renaming the existing file and creating a new one.If the existing file is open in eclipse ,it closes from it  and I have to open the file  again manually.

How can I open the file programmatically which is open it editor after renaming ?

Comment: What do you mean by **editor**?

Comment: If a file open in eclipse,that editor.

Comment: You mean you want to open a file in eclipse using java code, m I guessing right?

Comment: yes.but the file is now open in eclipse and and I am renaming it.After that I want to open the same file using java code as eclipse closed it automatically at the time of renaming.

Comment: Don't rename during export, rename from within eclipse and you should be all set.  [Granted, this might not work for your exact circumstance...]

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
IFile file = ...;
IEditorDescriptor desc = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().
    getEditorRegistry().getDefaultEditor(file.getName());
page.openEditor(new FileEditorInput(file), desc.getId());
```

If there are any more questions open ask or look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F